# Mocking Parametrized Constructor using Gmock

Tags: c++, constructor, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I have class to be mocked but it does not have a default constructor. I cannot change the source code, so is there any way to mock a parametrized constructor using Gmock

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes there is. Just let your Mock's constructor call the mocked class' constructor with the right arguments:

```
class base_class {
public:
    base_class(int, int) {}

    virtual int foo(int);
};


class base_mock : public base_class {
public:
    base_mock() : base_class(23, 42) {}

    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, int(int));
};
```

or even

```
class base_mock : public base_class {
public:
    base_mock(int a, int b) : base_class(a, b) {}

    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, int(int));
};
```

---

**Edit after request from @Blackhex**

Suppose our mocked class' constructor takes a reference to some other class it needs:

```
class helper2 {};
class helper {
public:
  helper(helper2&) {}

  /* Whatever */
};

class base2 {
public:
  base2(helper &h) {}

  virtual int foo(int);
};
```

Contrary to what I said in the comment, we do need to deal with all the helpers, unfortunately. However, that isn't too painful in this case as we do not need any of their functionality. We build simple, empty "plug" classes:

```
struct helper2_plug: public helper2 {};
struct helper_plug : public helper {
    helper_plug() : helper(helper2_plug()) {}
};
```

Then, we can build the mock:

```
class base2_mock : public base2 {
public:
    base2_mock() : base2(helper_plug()) {}

    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, int(int));
};
```

I used `struct` in my plugs just to avoid the `public`.

Comment: We do this all the time and there never was a problem. Could you elaborate what the problem is exactly? What have you tried? Does it compile? What are the error messages?

Comment: When the mocked class has constructor dependencies passed by reference that have other dependencies and so on, it leads to an explosion of mocks that are irrelevant to the tested case.

Comment: @Blackhex Not really. You'd have to mock the classes that are immediately passed into the constructor, not the whole cascade.

Comment: That's awesome news. Can you point us to some example of how to do it, please? You can add is as an answer to this post, I'd certainly upvote it.