# Mocking paramaterized constructor using strict Gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

I would like to mock a C++ class using Gmock; however, the class does not have a default constructor. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17465371/864027), but the solution does not work for me using *strict* mocks because I get the error

`type 'BaseClass' is not a direct base of 'MockClass'`

Any solutions?

Comment: Disclaimer I work at Typemock. With Isolator++ you can mock any class regardless to its base: `SomeClass* fakeClass= FAKE_ALL<SomeClass>();`

Answer (score 0):

The solution given in the answer you referenced should work fine for strict mocks, unless there's something unique about your code that makes it different. Here's an example of what I think you're trying to do, which compiles successfully:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int value) : _value(value) {}
    virtual void f() {}

private:
    int _value;
};

class MockA : public A {
public:
    MockA(int value) : A(value) {}
    MOCK_METHOD0(f, void());
};

TEST( StackOverflow, StrictMockNoDefaultConstructor ) {

    StrictMock<MockA> strictMockA(1);
}
```